# is there such a thing as a one-way definition?

Tags: logic

A definition always looks something like this:

> We say $P$ if and only if $Q$.

Is there an example of a definition where the biconditional is replaced with  "if" (and we mean just "if")? What about in the other direction?

Comment: Yes...that is called Conditional.

Comment: No? In a definition, there's always an expression which "has to be defined". A conditional (something of the form $P\implies Q$) doesn't require that.

Comment: In my opinion, definitions don't deserve to be called "definitions" unless they're of the form of "iff". That being said, many authors _phrase_ definitions using "if", letting it be implicit that they actually mean "iff".

Comment: A definition is an equivalence. It is not a definition if it is not an equivalence.

Comment: if it wasn't an equivalence it would be either impossible to prove that something is a P, or it would be impossible to deduce anything from knowing that something is a P. Pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: Every definition is a bi-conditional, but one direction is vacuous so we omit it for the purposes of logical aesthetic.

**Long answer**: Think about this in terms of what a definition is which is an assignment of meaning to a string of symbols. A string of symbols, say "$xyz$" has no inherent meaning unless we assign it one. So to say something like "A < something > is "$xyz$" if and only if < condition > " makes sense in both directions, but, because it is the first instance of "$xyz$" one direction in the statement ("< condition > $\implies$ "$xyz$" ") is vacuous because at that instance "$xyz$" means nothing in particular.